# Se puede optimizar este codigo? Graficos WinForms Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, revisión-de-código

Soy nuevo por aquí.

Este código lo tengo puesto en un formulario el cual genera los fondos del formulario.

Aclaro que el formulario está vació (sin controles) y tiene el `DoubleBuffer` activado.

Yo creo que consume demasiada memoria y cpu al ejecutarse, quizá solo sea por la cantidad de procesamiento que los colores/CGI+ demanda.

---

```
' Imports para Graficos
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D


Public Class Form1

    ' Gradient Generator (4 colors) from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339553/fill-panel-with-gradient-in-three-colors
    Private Function Gradient2D(ByVal r As Rectangle, ByVal c1 As Color, ByVal c2 As Color, ByVal c3 As Color, ByVal c4 As Color) As Bitmap
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height)
        Dim delta12R As Double = (1.0! * ((CDbl(c2.R) - c1.R) / r.Height))
        Dim delta12G As Double = (1.0! * ((CDbl(c2.G) - c1.G) / r.Height))
        Dim delta12B As Double = (1.0! * ((CDbl(c2.B) - c1.B) / r.Height))
        Dim delta34R As Double = (1.0! * ((CDbl(c4.R) - c3.R) / r.Height))
        Dim delta34G As Double = (1.0! * ((CDbl(c4.G) - c3.G) / r.Height))
        Dim delta34B As Double = (1.0! * ((CDbl(c4.B) - c3.B) / r.Height))
        Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Do While (y < r.Height)
            Dim c12 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, (c1.R + CType((y * delta12R), Integer)), (c1.G + CType((y * delta12G), Integer)), (c1.B + CType((y * delta12B), Integer)))
            Dim c34 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, (c3.R + CType((y * delta34R), Integer)), (c3.G + CType((y * delta34G), Integer)), (c3.B + CType((y * delta34B), Integer)))
            Dim lgBrush As LinearGradientBrush = New LinearGradientBrush(New Rectangle(0, y, r.Width, 1), c12, c34, 0!)
            G.FillRectangle(lgBrush, 0, y, r.Width, 1)
            y = (y + 1)
        Loop

        Return bmp
    End Function


    ' Imagen con los gradientes de colores de las esquinas
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(255, 8)

    ' Color Inicial
    Dim c1 As Color
    Dim c2 As Color
    Dim c3 As Color
    Dim c4 As Color
    ' Color Final
    Dim cc1 As Color
    Dim cc2 As Color
    Dim cc3 As Color
    Dim cc4 As Color
    ' Color en uso
    Dim t1 As Color
    Dim t2 As Color
    Dim t3 As Color
    Dim t4 As Color


    ' Operaciones de Dibujo de Formulario
    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

        ' Calidad de Graficos: La mas alta
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality

        ' Dibujo de Fondo de Colores
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Gradient2D(e.ClipRectangle, t1, t2, t3, t4), e.ClipRectangle)

    End Sub




    ' Calculos para determinar nuevos colores
    Dim TimeStart As TimeSpan = Now.TimeOfDay
    Dim TimeDuration As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)
    Sub GenerateNewColors()

        c1 = cc1
        c2 = cc2
        c3 = cc3
        c4 = cc4

        cc1 = RandomColor()
        cc2 = RandomColor()
        cc3 = RandomColor()
        cc4 = RandomColor()

    End Sub



    ' Creador de Colores aleatorios
    Dim r As New Random
    Function RandomColor() As Color
        Return Color.FromArgb(r.Next(0, 256), r.Next(0, 256), r.Next(0, 256))
    End Function




 ' Calculos para determinar color actual
    Dim x As Integer, g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
    Dim br As New LinearGradientBrush(New Rectangle(0, 0, 255, 2), c1, cc1, 0, False)
    Sub SetTemps()

        If Now.TimeOfDay > (TimeStart + TimeDuration) Then
            TimeStart = Now.TimeOfDay
            GenerateNewColors()



            ' g.Clear(Color.White)
            br.LinearColors = {c1, cc1}
            g.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(0, 0, 255, 2))

                br.LinearColors = {c2, cc2}
                g.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(0, 2, 255, 2))

                br.LinearColors = {c3, cc3}
                g.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(0, 4, 255, 2))

                br.LinearColors = {c4, cc4}
                g.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(0, 6, 255, 2))




        End If
        x = (CInt((Now.TimeOfDay - TimeStart).TotalSeconds * 255) / (TimeDuration.TotalSeconds))
        If x >= 255 Then x = 254
        t1 = bm.GetPixel(x, 0)
        t2 = bm.GetPixel(x, 2)
        t3 = bm.GetPixel(x, 4)
        t4 = bm.GetPixel(x, 6)

    End Sub




    ' Load
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ResizeRedraw = True
        Randomize()
    End Sub


    ' Show (Loop)
    Dim stopAll As Boolean = False
    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        While stopAll = False

            SetTemps()
            Me.Invalidate()

            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        stopAll = True
    End Sub




End Class
```

---

---

Ahora dejo las imagenes con el consumo:
[image: Recursos excesivos que consume el programa.]

---

Entonces mi pregunta es: es inevitable esta cantidad excesiva (si se le puede llamar asi) de consumo de CPU y RAM para estas operaciones de graficos? Me olvide de vaciar los recursos en algun lugar? Hay otra opción con resultados similares que me recomienden para obtener este tipo de graficos?

Desde ya muchas gracias por su atención. Atte, Pablo.

Comment: Analizar ese código es un poco complicado, pero si que te puedo decir que siempre hay que usar `Dispose` en los clases que implementan el interfaz `IDisposable`, bien manualmente, bien usando la estructura `Using`. Por ejemplo,haces `g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)`. Cuando acabes con `g`, debes liberar los recursos usando `g.Dispose()`, o mejor aun, englobar todo el código con `Using g As Graphics.FromImage(bm) .....End Using`.Solo con eso deberías notar una mejora.

Comment: @Pikoh, sería bueno que publicaras tu comentario como respuesta *(realmente para que tenga mas visibilidad)* o que la pregunta sea migrada a CodeReview.

Comment: Recién a la noche puedo volver a revisar el código. Voy a reformular las cosas con el <using>. Gracias!

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave en realidad estaba esperando a que el OP confirmara si la solucion realmente le servía de algo. Tambien tenía dudas sobre si la pregunta era pertinente,aunque podria entrar bajo el tag [tag:revision-de-codigo]

Comment: Hola. Usando los using no se resuelve. También probé ahora usar un BackGroundWorker para las operaciones de gráficos, aunque no hay ninguna mejora. De todas formas, gracias por responder!

Comment: Yo creo que la pregunta no corresonde: OP dice: "Yo creo que consume demasiada memoria y cpu al ejecutarse", basado en que? que tipo de profiling o comparacion hizo? estamos seguros que mas alla que tiene un problema de memory leak, que ya lo soluciono usando using, hay algun otro problema? esto corresponde mas a code review...

Comment: Puse `Yo creo` porque podría ser que no se pueda mejorar el código. Voy a revisar un poco más sobre el memory leak.

Comment: Ok. Ya reformulé todo el código con los using. Ahora consume 50-75mb de ram comparado con los 195mb de antes, está mucho mejor ahora. Aunque me di cuenta que depende mucho de el tamaño del formulario, así que ahora lo limito a 400x400. Gracias x la ayuda!

Comment: Ya que parece que liberar recursos con el uso de `Using` si ha ayudado, añado respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar memory leaks siempre hay que usar `Dispose` en las clases que implementan el interfaz `IDisposable`, bien manualmente, bien usando la estructura `Using`. Por ejemplo,haces `g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)`. Cuando acabes con `g`, debes liberar los recursos usando `g.Dispose()`, o mejor aun, englobar todo el código con:

```
Using g As Graphics.FromImage(bm)
    ' .....
End Using
```

Esto hace que una vez acabas de trabajar con los objetos, la memoria es correctamente desechada. Solo con eso deberías notar una mejora notable.